# why is react native maps not working after build in expo

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I have created a react native application with expo clii. In there I am using react-native-maps.With expo app It was very worked. But after building the standalone app and when I try to open it it did not navigate to that component.It mean when I click on the location tab it restart the app.This is my that component code.

Comment: any updates on this? can you post the current code?

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue when I build the app without a google maps api key in my `app.json`. After a build, the app would crash when I navigate to the component.

Can fix by putting your api key into `app.json`

```
expo: {
  ios: {
      config: {
        googleMapsApiKey: "API_KEY_HERE",
      },
    },
    android: {
      config: {
        googleMaps: {
          apiKey: "API_KEY_HERE",
        },
      },
    },
}
```

Read more [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/#deploying-app-with-google-maps)